# Github actions get SSH link of repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am using github actions to deploy to a server. Right now I wrote a small bash script to check if directory exists, if so `git pull` other wise `git clone`.

Everything is general, but I am not sure how to get the ssh link of the repository from the environment variables:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Create project dir
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        KEY: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: |
          mkdir -p ~/projects
          cd ~/projects
          if [ -d "${{ github.event.repository.name }}" ]; then
            echo "Directory already exists"
            cd ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
            git pull --rebase
          else
            git clone git@github.com:orgname/projectname.git
          fi
          echo 'Deployment to server succesful!'
```

So as we can see, `git clone git@github.com:orgname/projectname.git` is still hardcoded. How could I get this part general as well like `github.event.repository.name`?

---

*Edit for VonC:*

Output on GitHub actions:

```
  pwd
  ls -alrth
  git version
  echo "GURL=$(git remote get-url origin)">>$GITHUB_ENV
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
/home/runner/work/digitalocean-test-deploy/digitalocean-test-deploy
total 60K
drwxr-xr-x  3 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 tests
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 src
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 1.1K Dec 27 13:12 setup.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 settings
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   26 Dec 27 13:12 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 notebooks
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 docs
drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 data
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  516 Dec 27 13:12 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 1.1K Dec 27 13:12 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 1.8K Dec 27 13:12 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  3 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 .github
drwxr-xr-x 10 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 runner docker 4.0K Dec 27 13:12 .git
git version 2.29.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the [checkout action allows to run commands](https://github.com/actions/checkout#push-a-commit-using-the-built-in-token) in the checked out working tree, you could use [`$GITHUB_ENV` environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), since [`set-env` is deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/) since Oct. 2020:

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          echo "GURL=$(git remote get-url origin)">>$GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Create project dir
          git clone $GURL
```

[As discussed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51240931#51240931), though, this does not seem to work within a step using `ssh-action`, hence [`appleboy/ssh-action` issue 99](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/99) (Q4 2020).

Q1 2021: this was resolved with [the comment](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/99#issuecomment-756410183):

> The best way to do this is to build the clone URL yourself, something like this (untested):

```yaml
uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
env:
  REPO: ${{ github.repository }} # e.g. "appleboy/ssh-action"
  TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
with:
  envs: REPO,TOKEN
  script: |
    git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/$REPO.git
```

See also "[Easier builds and deployments using Git over HTTPS and OAuth](https://github.blog/2012-09-21-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth/)" from [Wynn Netherland](https://twitter.com/pengwynn).

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly your answer is an extra step as a replacement for my git clone right? Or is it more than that?

Comment: @Zal It is an addition step to store the URL in a variable, for you to use in your script from your next step.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Small side questions. Am I using the `script:` part correctly? Since you use `run:`

Comment: @Zal run: is a workflow command (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun). `with: script:` is an action *input* parameter given to the action you are using.

Comment: I actually tested this with a project where the project did not exists, so it had to do the `git clone $GURL` and the `GURL` env variable is empty. So it fails, any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @Zal Can you add `pwd` and `ls -alrth` and `git version` before the `git remote get-url` line? Just to check where you are at and what Git is used by this GitHub Action execution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226484/discussion-between-vonc-and-zal).